# InnoDB frequently updated table running slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, innodb

I have a very simple table to track users activity. It's structure is as following:

```
userId appId lastActivity

PRIMARY(userId, appId)
```

Table allows to track, if user is active within a specific application. It's updated once a minute for each user and read as frequently to count number of users online within a specific application.

Lately I've noticed, that updates took a while to perform:

```
2012-10-01 16:49:10 - WARN --> Heavy query; array (
  'caller' => 'updateActivity',
  'query' => 'INSERT INTO user_activity VALUES(4953, 1, 1349095750)
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastActivity = 1349095750',
  'elapsed' => 0.134618,
)
2012-10-01 18:26:06 - WARN --> Heavy query; array (
  'caller' => 'updateActivity',
  'query' => 'INSERT INTO user_activity VALUES(4533, 1, 1349101566)
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastActivity = 1349101566',
  'elapsed' => 0.581776,
)
2012-10-01 18:27:16 - WARN --> Heavy query; array (
  'caller' => 'updateActivity',
  'query' => 'INSERT INTO user_activity VALUES(5590, 1, 1349101636)
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastActivity = 1349101636',
  'elapsed' => 0.351321,
)
2012-10-01 20:54:32 - WARN --> Heavy query; array (
  'caller' => 'updateActivity',
  'query' => 'INSERT INTO user_activity VALUES(3726, 1, 1349110472)
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastActivity = 1349110472',
  'elapsed' => 0.758706,
)
```

Table uses InnoDB as storage engine.

**My questions**

1. Is there any problem at all?
2. Is there any problem in my design?
3. Where to start to find performace problems in this specific situation?

Comment: You should use MySQL profiling to see why it's working so slow. Use `SET PROFILING = 1; [query here that issues an update]; SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;` from within MySQL prompt or some other visual tool and it'll show you which part of the query execution took the most time. There can be a few causes for this behaviour - first and most obvious is using InnoDB with default settings (increase innod_buffer_pool).

Comment: Your primary index may be fragmented.  Drop and rebuild the index to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Table fits in 48Kb, containing less than 1000 records. I doubt innodb_buffer_pool has anything to do with this((

Answer (score 0):

Well it's InnoDb, it's not as performant as MyISAM (depending on the frequency of your inserts)
  You're trying to implement an event logging model here. If you ever want to produce useful long term (or even medium term stats), your model will fail because it basically forgets everything that happened before the last time. 
  I'd suggest you reimplement by

1. Lose the `update on duplicate` clause and simply perform a fresh insert per activity/event.           You shed the overhead on the update activity.
2. Convert your InnoDb engine to MyISAM, performance gains there too
3. If you carry out the above two, the PK will become unnecessary. As it stands now, it's of questionable use. Perhaps you should just go for a `Unique` index off the bat.

What all this leaves you with is just an efficient logging system that has the capacity to grow quite large. There is batch archiving option to deal with that further down the line

Comment: There is no need to log every activity, moreover database will grow out of million records very fast if I do that.


Thanks for MyISAM advice, but as far as I know its questionable:


        "InnoDB is faster in write-intensive (inserts, updates) tables because it utilizes row-level locking and only hold up changes to the same row that’s being inserted or updated."


That's why I've choosen InnoDB engine in the first place.